# XmlService.parse() not able to handle HTML tables

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for help from this community regarding the below issue.

```
// I am searching my Gmail inbox for a specific email

function getWeeklyEmail() {
  var emailFilter = 'newer_than:7d AND label:inbox AND "Report: Launchpad filter"';
  var threads = GmailApp.search(emailFilter, 0, 5);
  var messages=[];
  threads.forEach(function(threads)
                  {
                   messages.push(threads.getMessages()[0]);
           });
  return messages;
  }

// Trying to parse the HTML table contained within the email

function getParsedMsg() {

  var messages = getWeeklyEmail();
  var msgbody = messages[0].getBody();
  var doc = XmlService.parse(msgbody);
  var html = doc.getRootElement();
  var tables = doc.getDescendants();

  var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Messages1');
  templ.tables = [];

  return templ.evaluate(); 
}
```

The debugger crashes when I try to step over the XmlService.parse function. The msgbody of the email contains both text and HTML formatted table. I am getting the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBody' of undefined (line 19, file "Code")

If I remove the getParsedMsg function and instead just display the content of the email, I get the email body along with the element tags etc in html format.

Comment: When you check `messages` in the function `getParsedMsg`, what value will you retrieve? When the 1st index of the array has no value, such error message is shown. When the GmailMessages object is not included in the 1st index, an error like "not a function" occurs. How about this?

Comment: There is only 1 message at all times when the function is called. It retrieves the email body of the message. How do I include the GmailMessages object in the 1st index? Thanks mate!

Comment: Not sure if I can upload a screenshot of the debug session, but the array object does have a value of 1 when I step over  var msgbody = messages[0].getBody(); in the code. Now... I get this error: Exception: Error on line 10: The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared. (line 20, file "Code").                      @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `There is only 1 message at all times when the function is called. It retrieves the email body of the message. How do I include the GmailMessages object in the 1st index?`. I think that when the data is put using `push` to the empty array, it is added from 1st index. If my understanding is not correct, I apologize.

Comment: Hi ! So I have tried to reproduce your issue and I was able to run the script successfully but looking for messages with a specific subject ( i.e instead of ```Report: Launchpad filter``` I used ```subject: my subject```), so I believe that ```push``` is not causing a major issue. My question is, **what does ```Report: Launchpad filter``` refer to so that I can test with that too?** Also, I find relevant to notice that I got your same error message when there was no email with my specific subject (thus the undefined). Do you have messages with that criteria?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf - hey the "Report: Launchpad filter" is just my subject line in the email. I am returning messages with my search. I am publishing the messages to a html document, and I can the html file populated with the email content. So, I don't think that is the problem. IMO,  I think it is a problem with the email body (text+html tables) and the xmlparser service api. There is something in the email body that the parser service does not like. I saw another thread here from 2 years ago that said the xmlparser service works only for canonical xml. so not sure if that is the root cause.

Comment: I understand. **How are you creating/inserting your tables in the email body?** Are you copy/pasting them from sheets or docs or creating them in a script? I have tried to reproduce this with tables but I was consistently getting the error ```Error on line 1: The element type "br" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</br>".```.

Comment: Also, to my undestanding, you basically want to get these email tables to create an HTML file with them, am I right? In that case, would you be open to use other type of workaround instead of XML parser?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf - yes, I am open to using a workaround instead of xml parser.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf - the tables are coming from a salesforce report embedded inside the body of the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Workaround

Hi ! The issue you are experiencing is due to *(as you previously mentioned)* [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service) only recognising canonical XML rather than HTML. One possible workaround to solve this issue is to search in the string you are obtaining with [getBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getbody) for your desired tags.

In your case your main issue is `var doc = XmlService.parse(msgbody);`. To solve it you could iterate through the whole string looking for the **table tags** you need using Javascript [search](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp) method. Here is an example piece of code retrieving an email with a single table:

```js
function getWeeklyEmail() {
  var emailFilter = 'newer_than:7d AND label:inbox AND "Report: Launchpad filter"';
  var threads = GmailApp.search(emailFilter, 0, 5);
  var messages=[];
  threads.forEach(function(threads)
                  {
                   messages.push(threads.getMessages()[0]);
           });
  return messages;
  }

// Trying to parse the HTML table contained within the email

function getParsedMsg() {

  var messages = getWeeklyEmail();
  var msgbody = messages[0].getBody();
  var indexOrigin = msgbody.search('<table');
  var indexEnd = msgbody.search('</table');
  // Get what is in between those indexes of the string.
  // I am adding 8 as it indexEnd only gets the first index of </table
  // i.e the one before <
  var Table = msgbody.substring(indexOrigin,indexEnd+8);
  Logger.log(Table);

}
```

If you are looking for more than one table in your message, you can change `getParsedMsg` to the following:

```js
function getParsedMsg() {
// If you are not sure about how many you would be expecting, use an approximate number
  var totalTables = 2;

  var messages = getWeeklyEmail();
  var msgbody = messages[0].getBody();
  
  var indexOrigin = msgbody.indexOf('<table');
  var indexEnd = msgbody.indexOf('</table');
  
  var Table = []
  for(i=0;i<totalTables;i++){
  
    // go over each stable and store their strings in elements of an array
    var start = msgbody.indexOf('<table', (indexOrigin + i))
    var end = msgbody.indexOf('</table', (indexEnd + i))
    
    Table.push(msgbody.substring(start,end+8));
  }
    Logger.log(Table);
}
```

This will let you store each table in an element of an array. If you want to use these you would just need to retrieve the elements of this array and use them accordingly (for exaple to use them as HTML tables.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Comment: Thanks for your assist. It doesn't seem to work. I get an error with msgbody.search not being a valid function inside of google script. Anyways, I am scrapping this effort for now.

Comment: Hi ! What exact error are you getting? Could you show it to me? Also, before runnning ```msgbody.search()``` could you write ```Logger.log(typeof(msgbody));``` and let me know what your Log tells you? (to make sure ```msgbody``` is a string).

Comment: Hey, so your workaround does work. The `Logger.log(typeof(msgbody));` does log string. What I did notice in the output is that, there are multiple tables in the email body. Now I need to go find a way to actually output this file in a table format, or build another script to take this output file and format it into a nice table so I can publish it into a google sheets doc.

Comment: Hi, I have eddited my answer accordingly to satisfy your situation of having more than one table. Does this fit your case?